# PHP 5 SSH2 functions

Tags: php, ssh, libssh2

I have installed and enabled SSH2 in my CentOS WHM/CPanel server, here is from PHP INFO:

ssh2
SSH2 support    enabled
extension version   0.11.2
libssh2 version     0.18
banner  SSH-2.0-libssh2_0.18
remote forwarding   enabled
hostbased auth  enabled
polling support     enabled
publickey subsystem     enabled

Registered PHP Streams  https, ftps, compress.zlib, php, file, glob, data, http, ftp, ssh2.shell, ssh2.exec, ssh2.tunnel, ssh2.scp, ssh2.sftp

However, anytime I try to use the SSH2 PHP functions to receive a file, I get this:

> Warning: ssh2_scp_recv(/home/XXXX) [function.ssh2-scp-recv]: failed to
>   open stream: Is a directory in /pathtoFile on line 16

Here's the code:

```
if($connection = ssh2_connect('www.server.com', 22)){
    echo("connected");
}else{
    echo("NOT connected");
}

if(ssh2_auth_password($connection, 'username', 'mypassword')){
    echo("password ok");
}else{
    echo("password WRONG");
}

if(ssh2_scp_recv($connection, '/home/pathtoDLfile', '/home/pathtoLocationDestination')){
    echo("received");
}else{
    echo("NOT received");
}

echo("end");
```

Comment: You sure you have the path to the file correct?  `'/home/username/pathtoDLfile'`, maybe?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please check '/home/pathtoDLfile' and '/home/pathtoLocationDestination' to ensure that they are file names, not directory.

Note especially that the destination location ('/home/pathtoLocationDestination') needs to be a file name, not just a directory path. You can append your desired filename to the path if you have currently specified only the directory name.

Answer (score 4):

It looks like you've specified a directory for the location to save your file to, rather than a filename.